# sql natural sort by strings mixed with numbers in one label

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, numbers, sql-order-by

I came with a problem of sorting using ORDER BY. I found a lot of similar questions, but no answer fits my needs. The task is:

I have column [LABEL] which contains strings, and i want to get an order like this:
label

`'1'
'2'
'11R'
'11T9'
'11T10'
'RT_5'
'RT_6'
'RT_10'
'RT_10b'
'RT_10dyn'
and so on...`

instead of:

`'1'
'11R'
'11T10'
'11T9'
'2S'
'RT_10'
'RT_10b'
'RT_10dyn'
'RT_5'
'RT_6'`

the label columb might be like any combination of characters.
The problem is to find numbers in names, and if it is possible to sort by those numbers, then by other charaters...

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server]+natural+sort

Answer (score 1):

You can substr  [LABEL] column into different columns and then order by those columns. As null is sorted first you don't need to do anything extra for values with less character.

How ever you can also follow this [thread here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51602/How-to-Sort-Alphanumeric-Data-in-SQL).

Here in this solution the logic is :-

1. If ID is numeric, add 21 '0's in front of the ID value and get the last 20 characters.
2. If ID is not numeric, add 21 ‘’s at the end of the ID value and get the first 20 characters.

Or this is a better solution for you query [Sort Alphanumeric value](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/842541/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-Server-to-Sort-Alphanumeric-Value?msg=4964874#xx4964874xx)

Let us see if it helps.

Comment: 1st solution is ok, when you know the structure of [label]. If not - you have to assume some number of additional columns. Once you do that, specific case can occure: when amount of numbers in [label] exeeds number of columns..

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as [pi.314](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928838/pi-314) but rewrite for PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnNumberAwareSort(value varchar, digits integer)
RETURNS varchar
AS '
DECLARE
    numbers VARCHAR[];
    texts VARCHAR[];
BEGIN
    value = CONCAT(''_'', value, ''_'');
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT res[1] FROM regexp_matches(value, ''\d+'', ''g'') AS res) INTO numbers;
    texts = regexp_split_to_array(value, ''\d+'');
    FOR i IN 1..array_upper(texts,1) LOOP 
        numbers[i] = lpad(numbers[i], digits, ''0'');
    END LOOP;
    value = texts[1];
    FOR i IN 2..array_upper(texts,1) LOOP
        value = value || numbers[i-1] || texts[i];
    END LOOP;
    RETURN value;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```